# Which one makes more sense Swap or Trade?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

I am building a website where you can give a thing you own and get another thing of the same kind in return. Say you give a stamp in exchange <strike>of</strike> for another stamp, so you change stamps with someone. Stamp is just an example, it could be a book, a game etc. Fundamentally what you do is giving and taking things of the same kind, you cannot give a book and get a game. You give a book, you get a book.

So, what I am wondering is which word would be the best to indicate this kind of exchange. Swap of Trade? What is the main difference between these two words?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: To exchange something for something else is the primary sense of `trade` and secondary sense of `swap`. The primary sense of `swap` meets your requirements. (We swap stories or phone numbers.) I'd go with `swap`.

Comment: @TusharRaj I would have expected nothing less from one from that great cricket-playing nation. Quite right. Well done.

Comment: @WS2 - I disagree with Tushar's assertion that _swap_ has a "primary" and "secondary" sense. I'm guessing that assertion based on [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/swap#swap), yet [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/swap_1#swap_4) lists those same meanings in reverse. In fact, either word could be used.

Comment: @J.R. I had never heard the word *trade* used in the sense of exchanging something until I was in my twenties and met an American for the first time.

Comment: @WS2: Wow. Supposedly that verb sense dates from the 1500s. You're older than you look!

Comment: @WS2 - Now I'm really confused. `Tushar:` To exchange something for something else is the primary sense of _trade_. `WS2 (to Tushar):` Quite right. Well done. `WS2 (to J.R.):` I had never heard the word _trade_ used in the sense of exchanging something until I was in my twenties and met an American. o_O

Comment: @J.R. *Trade* in the sense of the commercial trade in goods has been around for centuries and of course I had heard that used. What I had never heard until the 1960s was *trade* used as a verb to describe someone swapping half a dozen marbles for a packet of chewing gum. 'Trade' involved businesses, and in Britain still mostly does. Exchanging things at a personal level is called *swapping*.

Comment: @WS2 - Thanks! I appreciate the clarification. Makes much more sense now, and very interesting to know. I think the terms are more interchangeable here in the U.S., especially over the past few decades.

Comment: So when I read all that has been written here I understand swap is the better choice according to my question?

Answer (score 3):

Swap and trade are similar. Trade is more generic while swap has a much more casual feel. Swap can also mean exchanging something without either side giving up anything, though you could use trade in this way, too, I suppose.

For cultural context, there are large "swap meets" in certain parts of America. LA is famous for them. They are sometimes mentioned in rap music. So, if you want to be cool, go with swap and leave trade to the economics professors. Too bad swapmeet.com isn't likely to be available!

Comment: So when I read all that has been written here I understand swap is the better choice according to my question?

Comment: I would use swap, but trade isn't incorrect. It depends on the feeling you're going for. I don't know if there's a word that means exchange one type of thing for something else of the same type. We would usually qualify swap/exchange/trade with whatever we were swapping/exchanging/or trading, i.e. book swap, card exchange, etc. Note, however, that "book trade" is also a colloquial way of referring to the business of book publication. Likewise for other products.